# How to handle too long equations?

Tags: align

I have some equations that don't fit in one line. In addition, they have different heights. I think it looks awful.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\int_{E} \operatorname{Re}  ((Q f)(x) - g(x))^2 \mu(dx) &=
\int_{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(m_i) \,1_{A_i} (x)
- \operatorname{Re}(g(x))\right)^2 \mu(dx)\\
&=
\int_{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n  \operatorname{Re}(m_i) \,1_{A_i}(x) \right)^2
  -2 \sum_{i=1}^n  \operatorname{Re}(m_i)\,1_{A_i}(x)\, \operatorname{Re}(g(x)) \\
  & \quad +  \operatorname{Re}(g(x))^2 \mu(dx)\\
  &=
\int_{E}  \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(m_i)^2\, 1_{A_i}(x) 
  -2 \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(m_i) \,1_{A_i}(x)\, \operatorname{Re}(g(x))
  \\ 
  & \quad + \operatorname{Re}(g(x))^2 \mu(dx)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n  \int_{A_i}  \operatorname{Re}(m_i)^2 
  -2 \operatorname{Re}(m_i)\, \operatorname{Re}( g(x))\\
  & \quad + \operatorname{Re}(g(x))^2 \mu(dx)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{A_i}
(\operatorname{Re}(g(x) - m_i )^2 \mu(dx)
\end{align*}    

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Is there any chance to make it look better?

Comment: You could start with replacing the first align*-line by `&\hphantom{{}={}}\int_{E} \operatorname{Re}  ((Q f)(x) - g(x))^2 \mu(dx) \\ `, then the `\\  & \quad ` can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\int_{E} \operatorname{Re} &  ((Q f)(x) - g(x))^2 \mu(dx) =
\int_{E} \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(m_i) \,1_{A_i} (x)
- \operatorname{Re}(g(x))\Big)^2 \mu(dx)\\
&=
\int_{E} \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n  \operatorname{Re}(m_i) \,1_{A_i}(x) \Big)^2
  -2 \sum_{i=1}^n  \operatorname{Re}(m_i)\,1_{A_i}(x)\, \operatorname{Re}(g(x)) 
  +  \operatorname{Re}(g(x))^2 \mu(dx)\\
  &=
\int_{E}  \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(m_i)^2\, 1_{A_i}(x) 
  -2 \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Re}(m_i) \,1_{A_i}(x)\, \operatorname{Re}(g(x))
   + \operatorname{Re}(g(x))^2 \mu(dx)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n  \int_{A_i}  \operatorname{Re}(m_i)^2 
  -2 \operatorname{Re}(m_i)\, \operatorname{Re}( g(x))
  + \operatorname{Re}(g(x))^2 \mu(dx)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{A_i}
(\operatorname{Re}(g(x) - m_i )^2 \mu(dx)
\end{align*}    

\end{document}
```

I hardly ever use `\left` / `\right` brackets, since they usually are too massive (unless you `\smash{}` the things inside). Better fine tune with `\big`, `\Big` and so on...

Comment: And `\DeclareMathOperator\re{Re}` in the preamble, using `\re` instead all of this `\operatorname{Re}` would be awesome.

Comment: I thought to a similar solution, but leaving only the left hand side in the first line. I endorse Manuel's advice and I'd also remove all the `\,` commands. Surely `\left` and `\right` are to avoid when enclosing a summation symbol, preferring `\biggl` and `\biggr` (maybe `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` are still too small). However the `l` and `r` variants should be used rather the unadorned `\Big`.

Comment: Super helpful. I would like to just add that if equation number is required use `\begin{align}` (without `*`) and use `\nonumber` before line-breaks through `\\\`